# Rscript error 400

Tags: r, elasticsearch, rscript

I have a R script (script.R) that loads 25-30K documents in elasticsearch in each execution.

The point is that I can execute it in Rstudio properly. However, when I try to execute it from command line using Rscript I always get the same error:

```
Error: 400 - failed to parse
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
Execution halted
```

The strangest thing is that when this error occurs there are loaded different amount of documents in elastic (sometimes 1.5K, sometimes 3K, etc...). So it seems that it doesn't occurs always at same time.

Do you know what's happening? This is the Rscript execution:

```
/usr/bin/Rscript /Rdir/script.R
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the execution on the same system? Are the environment variables the same when you execute it cmdline vs in RStudio? Is it being executed from the same account? Are you in a differerent directory on the cmdline and are there local project/folder `.Rprofile`/`.Renviron` files overriding assumptions? Knowing what basic debugging systems and more details abt your system(s) would be helpful since this is a computing environment question and not really an R programming question and is likely to get closed as such.

Comment: You're right, I execute in RStudio in a different system. However, the environment variables are the same and the execution is done in the same project with no .Rprofile/.Renviron files overriding.

Comment: unpossible. there is a system/environmental difference you're not accounting for. If not R environment or profile then memory constraints, different API key in a different location or something else. Or, perhaps, even different R & R package versions. You should dump sessionInfo() on both systems along with the out Sys.getenv() and do a detailed comparison. to see what's different (in script context and just in general)

Comment: Give https://github.com/hrbrmstr/triage a try. I threw it together to make it easier to dump almost all of the things that make an R session unique (without dumping the objects from the global environment, just metadata).

Comment: @DanielM.M. are you using `elastic` pkg?  not sure if this is a problem with `elastic`, but if it is let me know

Comment: Hi @sckott. yes, I am using `elastic` pkg and I am totally sure that I get the 400 error executing the `docs_create` function. Do you think this could be a bug?

Comment: @DanielM.M. can you open an issue in the `elastic` repo would be best https://github.com/ropensci/elastic/issues

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the issue using elastic::docs_bulk function instead of elastic::docs_create. It seems to work better with a huge amount of documents in elastic.